# I have added this in my Bloggerspot blog's robot txt file, is it in the correct format?

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt, blogspot

```
User-agent:*
Disallow:
Allow:/
Sitemap:https://example.com/?m=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the allow and the sitemap should point to one.  I have normally seen spaces after the colon, so -

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Allow: /
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```